# lightning check box field set default as true

Tags: lightning

I am trying to set checkbox value as default. Below is the code.

```
 <label class="slds-form-element__label">Is Active</label>
    <force:inputField  value="{!v.Opp.Active__c}" />
```

Can someone let me know how to set.

Comment: As you are using `force:inputField` try to set the checkbox field default value set to `checked` instead of `unchecked` that must show you checked it on the new record. It's just a guess not sure it will work or not.

Answer (score 1):

The place to populate default data values is either in your declaration of your `<aura:attribute>`:

```
<aura:attribute name="contact" type="Contact" 
           default="{ 'sobjectType': 'Contact', 'LastName': 'Schmoe' }"/>
```

or in your controller, if, for example, you wish to populate data from the server into an attribute and then make changes, or dynamically create a new object:

```
({
     doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getContact");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                let cont = response.getReturnValue();
                cont.LastName = "Schmoe";
                // Add a default value (not persisted to the database!)
                component.set("v.contact", cont);
            }
         });
         $A.enqueueAction(action); 
    }     
})
```

Answer (score 0):

if opp is the attribute name, then do this in your init function

```
var oppDefault = cmp.get("v.opp");
oppDefault.active__c=true;
cmp.set("v.opp",oppDefault);
```

*

Note : Syntax might not be accurate, you get the idea that defaulting should be in attribute default parameter for strings etc, or in the init function for objects

*

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set it in doInit method.
Below is the sample code.

Code in Component

```
<force:inputField value="{!v.Opp.Active__c}">
```

Code in controller

```
doInit : function(cmp, event, helper){
    var opp = cmp.get("v.Opp");
    opp.Active__c = true;
    cmp.set('v.Opp', opp);
}
```

Comment: I have to make Active__c = true when opp.Type = 'New'. If opp.Type = 'Old' then Active__c=false.